# Retrieve ContentPart using IContentManager, filtered by case-insensitive field

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms, orchard-modules

In the development of an Orchard module, how do I retrieve ContentParts case insensitively filtered by a field? I have tried

```
var name = viewModel.Name.ToUpper();
var samples = _contentManager.Query<SamplePart, SamplePartRecord>()
                .Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == name)
                .List();
```

and I'm getting an error

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index
```

but when I tried to retrieve without bothering if it's case sensitive

```
var name = viewModel.Name;
var samples = _contentManager.Query<SamplePart, SamplePartRecord>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == name)
                .List();
```

No errors reported.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the expression inside the `Where` clause is being translated by NHibernate to an SQL query at some point. Hence you're pretty restricted to what you can do there. In this case it seems like the `ToUpper` method is not supported.

Another thing - the string comparison behavior in SQL Server depends on the actual collation set on your database. By default it's case insensitive, so any string comparison will ignore case. So, if you stick to defaults you're good with just an ordinary `==` on two strings, like in your last example.

Comment: My database collation is indeed SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (case insensitive). Thanks